# CakePHP using Session outside of the function

Tags: session, cakephp, authentication

I have a piece of code that is responsible for the pagination in my controllers:

```
var $paginate = array(
            'limit' => 5,
            'conditions' => array('Tanque.user_id' => 1),
            'order' => array(
            'Tanque.nome' => 'asc'
        )
    );
```

So, where I have `'Tanque.user_id' => 1`, I would like to use the `user_id` instead of the number `1`. I am getting the `user_id` from the Session `$this->Session->read('Auth.User.id')`, but I get an error.

How can I use the `$this->Session->read` outside of the functions?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use *expressions* in class declarations, you can only use static values. Not to mention that all the components aren't even loaded at this stage. Do this in a function, like `beforeFilter`:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->paginate['conditions']['Tanque.user_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');
    parent::beforeFilter();
}
```